# Is load time Bytecode Instrumentation done in parallel in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

So, I made my own Java agent which has a `ClassFileTransformer` in it which implements the `transform` method. What I observed is that this method is called on different threads.
I checked it with `Thread.currentThread()`
These are the different threads:

```
Thread[background-preinit,5,main]
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[cluster-ClusterId{value='...', description='null'}-localhost:27017,5,main]
```

Comment: Which kind of transformation are you talking about? Load-time transformation? I’d expect load-time transformation happening in the same thread that triggered the particular class loading.

Comment: @Holger edited the title, thanks for pointing out this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ClassFileTransformer` is applied in the thread that loads a class for the first time. In case of a retransformation, all loaded classes are instrumented in the thread that invokes `Instrumentation.retransformClasses`.

Therefore: yes, retransformation happens in multiple threads.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Thank you!